# WebApi2 Attribute Routing 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routeattribute

I upgraded an existing MVC4/WebAPI1 project to MVC5/WebAPI2 in Visual Studio 2012 as described [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2).  The site worked as expected.  I then followed the directions for attribute based routing found [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) - except I keep getting a 404 for the controllers.  My steps were:

- Add config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in WebApiConfig.Register
- Add config.EnsureInitialized(); in WebApiConfig.Register
- Add AttributeRouting (ASP.NET WebAPI) from NuGet
- Add the Route attribute on my test controller

I see that the test route is getting registered when I put a break after config.EnsureInitialized().  However, trying to hit that route gives me a 404.

If there any way out of the box to inspect the request and see how the routing table is being matched?

Comment: Which package are you referring to when you say `Add AttributeRouting (ASP.NET WebAPI) from NuGet`...attribute routing is built-into Web API and you need not be installing any other extra package to have it working...are you by chance installing Tim McCall's attribute routing package instead?

Comment: Yes, it was.  I reverted the changes (thank goodness for source control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Route Debugger` to inspect all Routes. There's an official post from MSDN that covers this:

- [Debugging ASP.NET Web API with Route Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

I had the almost the same issues. And cannot find any working solution.
The Route debugger is really doesn't work with Web API 2.
Finally, I've found a working way to debug Web API 2 including Route Attributes.

[Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/)

Нope this helps someone save a few hours of debuging.

Comment: How did that help? Can you explain what you did with that link? I tried installing the package mentioned in the link but Route Debugger still doesn't work.

Comment: I think that what he meant was that by installing the HelpPage package you would be able to navigate to /help and see all your WebApi routes, URL parameters and/or body parameters from which you could be able to pinpoint problems

Comment: Simply installing it helped me - but I think only because it installed several dependency packages that I must have been missing - all in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi namespace. I think it's a case of mysterious-missing-dependency syndrome. Seems to happen a lot to me lately. :-\

Comment: hmmmm.. installing Help page didn't work for me - but, it does make some very nice help pages and *it does properly enumerate my routes* .. but I still get 404 errors. FWIW:  [Here's info on how to use help page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)